# What do the argument values end up in arydshln's \adl@drawi and \adl@drawii?

Tags: sourcecode, arydshln

I am trying to understand the arydshln package. From what I understand, the entire thing is built upon basic TeX `\xleaders`. I would like to get back to the basics too. Unfortunately, although the style file is well-organized, it is difficult to figure out which values end up where.

- `\adl@drawi#1#2#3`
- `\adl@drawii#1#2#3`
- `\adl@drawiii#1#2#3`

Then you have stuff like this going on:

- `\let\adl@draw\adl@drawi`

So `#3` should be a box or rule, because it is what `\xleaders` expects, then `#2` some glue. I am not sure what `#1` is.

[image]

## arydshln.sty Snippet

After a quick `\xleaders` search, I found this. What are the values of `#1`, `#2`, and `#3` in the code below? I have been trying to sort it out, but I keep getting lost in the code.

```
\def\adl@drawi#1#2#3{%
        #1{.5}#2.5\@tempdimb
        \xleaders#3{#2.5\@tempdimb #1{1}#2.5\@tempdimb}%
                #2\z@ plus1fil minus1fil\relax
        #2.5\@tempdimb #1{.5}}
\def\adl@drawii#1#2#3{%
        \setbox\adl@box#3{#2.5\@tempdimb #1{1}#2.5\@tempdimb}%
        #1{.5}#2.5\@tempdimb
        \copy\adl@box #2-\@tempdima #2-\@tempdimb
        \xleaders\copy\adl@box#2\z@ plus1fil minus1fil\relax
        #2-\@tempdima #2-\@tempdimb \copy\adl@box
        #2.5\@tempdimb #1{.5}}
\def\adl@drawiii#1#2#3{{\let\xleaders\cleaders \adl@drawi#1#2#3}}
\let\adl@draw\adl@drawi
```

Comment: Did you try `\tracingall`?

Comment: @JosephWright Hey that is pretty useful with `grep`. It is still a pain to figure out what is going on. It could be that I am not looking for the right things though.

Comment: you might find some help in the manual with the documented code.  `texdoc -l arydshln` lists all the options and allows you to select.  the choice should be obvious.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh wow. That is well-documented. I was so focused that I missed that. I think I had a different help document open without so much code. p43-44

Comment: yes, simply asking for `texdoc arydshln` brings up the user manual, which is only the first part.  the `-l` ("ell") is often more helpful if you need more than a simple "how do i do this" pointer.

Comment: @macmadness86 some of us have spent a _lot_ longer looking at tex `\tracingall` output than its typeset output....

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in the [manual for `arydshln`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/arydshln/arydshln.pdf) (at time of writing p.43-44).

1. rule
2. skip
3. box

> These three macros have common interface, `\@tempdima` and `\@tempdimb` for the length of dash and gap, *d* and *g*, and three arguments *rule*, *skip* and *box* with which `\adl@draw` is called in the following manner.
>
> `\adl@draw\adl@vrule\hskip\hbox` . . . horizontal
>
> `\adl@draw\adl@hrule\vskip\vbox` . . . vertical